# How to get rid of light border around inserted images in Microsoft Visio?

Tags: png, pixels, border, microsoft-visio-2007

When inserting a raster PNG image into Microsoft Visio 2007, it tries to make it smoother by interpolating pixel colors. It seems like Visio interpolates border pixels with white as if image was surrounded by white border. Since the image was created to have background that matches the background on the page, it is important that border pixel color is unchanged, which is not the case. In print this border is clearly visible.

Compare image in Visio (background is created by the filled rectangle):

[image: Inserted image in Visio]

with actual image in Paint:

[image: Actual image in Paint]

As you can see lighter border is not present in the original image. How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that using "Publish to PDF" function fixed the problem. Final PDF didn't have the border anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that Saving/Publishing to PDF creates a PDF that does not show the border.

However, an alternative way is to use the cropping tool in Visio.  In Visio 2010, select the image and it's on the Picture Tools Format ribbon.